# Getting a 405 for POST request to WebAPI service from ASP.NET - right handler seems to be called

Tags: asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api

I've got a WebAPI service on my dev box that I am try to call from an ASP.NET web site, also hosted on my dev box. GET requests work fine. However, POST requests return a 405.

The two most common causes I've seen mentioned here are that an IIS handler is catching the request before WebAPI can get it, or that you don't have Cors properly installed for JavaScript. Neither seem to apply here, since I've checked my handler configuration and I'm not making the service call via JavaScript.

The code making the request from the ASP.NET application is:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    Uri destination = new Uri("http://PromotionCodeProviderService/api/PromotionCode/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    string newCodeJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newCode);
    HttpContent postContent = new ByteArrayContent(newCodeJson.ToRawByteArray());

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(destination, postContent).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return true; 
    }
    else
    {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

On the service side, the routing is:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

And the controller code is:

```
public class PromotionCodeController : ApiController
{
    private readonly PromotionCodeService _promotionCodeService; 

    public PromotionCodeController()
    {
        _promotionCodeService = new PromotionCodeService();            
    }

    // GET api/values
    public List<PromotionCode> Get()
    {
        return _promotionCodeService.GetPromotionCodes();
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        PromotionCode newCode = Json.Decode<PromotionCode>(value); 
        _promotionCodeService.AddPromotionCode(newCode);
    }
...
```

If I call the service using a GET method, I get into the Get() method above and it returns values happily. If I call the service using a POST method, I get the following response:

```
{StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Fri, 05 Aug 2016 19:09:10 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 73
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}
```

The only handlers in my applicationHost.config that aren't limited to specific file paths are:

```
<add name="TRACEVerbHandler" path="*" verb="TRACE" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" />
<add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" />
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
<add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
```

And the handlers for my service's web.config are:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />

  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />

</handlers>
```

If I comment out the ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 handler in my service's web.config, the error changes from a 405 to a 404, so I'm pretty sure the POST request is getting routed to the right handler - it seems like something is going bad after that.

Thanks very much to anyone who can help out.

Comment: With it running as two separate sites, have you accounted for CORS?

Comment: Would I need to? The request to the service isn't coming directly from the browser. It's initiated by the ASP.NET application on the server side.

Comment: Are you able to call the Post method using fiddler or postman?

Comment: I've been using the Advanced REST Client app from the Google store to send requests directly (https://advancedrestclient.com/). That gives the same 405 error on POST that the ASP.NET app receives.